# Angularjs sharing data between controllers only works 1st time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to share data between controllers in angularjs using a factory. I have followed other answers to similar questions but I can only get this to work 1st time round. I have an app with 3 states. 1 of the states is a simple calculator. I want the total in the calculator state to also be displayed in a different state. With the code below the total is always displayed as 0. So i think it works 1st time round but does not update when 'total' is changed. Anyone any suggestions??

html:

```
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-divider">Total</div>
  <div class="item item-body">
    <div ng-model="figure">
      <b>{{figure}}</b> calories consumed today
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

'home' controller:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, total) {

$scope.figure = total.get();

})
```

calculator controller:

```
.controller('calcCtrl', function($scope, total) {

$scope.result = 0;

$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.result = 0;

};

$scope.add = function(i) {
    if(!i){

    }else {
        $scope.result = $scope.result + parseInt(i);
        total.set($scope.result);

    }
};

});
```

factory

```
.factory('total', function() {

var val = 0;

return {
get: function() {
    return val;
},
set: function(num) {
    val = parseInt(num);
    }
};  
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: Share data between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers)

Comment: Yes, i studied the answers there and thought I have done everything as they did but I still cannot get the data shared.

Comment: You're binding to a primitive. See how he binds to an object in that answer? Return an object instead of a value from your service and bind to the `object.prop`.

Comment: Thanks @NeilSmith. Got it working. I thought I had studied the previous answer! obviously not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work better if you use an object to store the value(s).

```
var data = {val : 0};
return {
  get: function() {
    return data;
  },
  set: function(num) {
    data.val = parseInt(num);
  }
};
```

or you always call the get() function to get the latest value

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, total) {
   $scope.figure = total.get;
})
```

and in the HTML

```
<b>{{figure()}}</b>
```